# How to I use terminal-function-details?

Tags: terminal

recently started working in the terminal Vim provides with `:terminal`. Reading through the man pages of this I reached the section on Terminal functions, which seem quite interesting. However, I'm not sure how and where to invoke these functions. How do I for instance use the `term_dumpwrite()` function?

Comment: It would help greatly if you were to [edit] to explain your objectives/what problem you faced—what are you trying to do? what's the end goal? "How to use `term_dumpwrite`" -> `:call term_dumpwrite(...)`...

Comment: Ah, the missing piece for me was `:call`, thanks. If you make an answer, I'll accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use any function, you can either `call` it:

```
call term_dumpwrite(...)
```

Or place it in “expression position”:

```
echo f(...)
let a = f(...)
```

Etc.